# Need to link product to variation_id on WooCommerce (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We're trying to solve a problem with our woocommerce website. We made custom product fields using HTML mostly: http://studentlens.nu/shop/testproduct/testproduct/

However, it's not linked to the product yet, while the option values are linked to the attributes. For example, the variable 'Cylinder' at the section 'Linkeroog' looks like this in the variable.php:

```
<td class="label"><label for="model">Cylinder</label></td>
<td class="value">
<select id="pa_cylinder-links" class="kad-select" name="attribute_pa_cylinder-links">
<option value="">Kies een optie...</option>
<option value="2-25" class="active">-2.25</option>
<option value="1-75" class="active">-1.75</option>
<option value="1-25" class="active">-1.25</option>
<option value="0-75" class="active">-0.75</option>
<option value="selecteer-geen-cylinder-links">Selecteer geen cylinder</option>
</select>
</td>
```

So we need to link the variation_id to the product. Thank you in advance :)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129730/how-to-get-woocommerce-variation-id

Comment: Yes Robert I'm aware of that topic. However, also there, the problem isn't entirely solved.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure if this is what you are looking for.  http://blueskysessions.com/2014/03/31/woocommerce-display-dynamic-content-per-the-selected-product-variation/

Comment: Nah, that's about the display.. the problem is with the attributes, i.e. linking it with the actual product in the back end.